# Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'. Please use a nullable type.-Query SharePoint list data linqtoSQL

Tags: linq, sharepoint, linq-to-sql

I have a LinqToSQL query it should check ReturnedDate is empty from SharePoint list.
I wrote below query and returns error in runtime as "**Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'. Please use a nullable type.**"

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> x = from student in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                     join d in dt1.AsEnumerable() on student.Field<string>("Name") equals d.Field<string>("LapName")
                                     where d.Field<DateTime>("ReturnedDate") ==Convert.ToDateTime("")
                                     select student;
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast **ReturnedDate** when it's Null. So you have to check that before.
I think you could use:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> x = from student in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                 join d in dt1.AsEnumerable() on student.Field<string>("Name") equals d.Field<string>("LapName")
                                 where d.Field<DateTime?>("ParentId").HasValue
                                 select student;
```

Comment: Error at returned date: The type arguments for method 'System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field<T>(System.Data.DataRow, int)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @SivakumarPiratheeban, I updated my answer. Cast it to a nullable DateTime (with: '?'), and check if that has a value.